# how to return list  of emails in database ,erray info

Tags: android, sqlite

How to return a list in a column e.g like all emails in column...here my code

```
public String reTurn() throws SQLException 
{

    String emails=null;

    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT EmailNO FROM  Details_Customer " ,null); 
    mCursor.moveToFirst(); 


    if(mCursor.getCount() > 0){ 
        emails= mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COLUMN_EMAIL)); 
        //password = mCursor.getString(11);
    }
return emails;
  }
```

But it only returning one email, I want it to return all the emails in a database

Comment: Change your if statement into a loop to get all the emails. Or I think you could use a cursor adapter.

Comment: How can I do that? please help

Comment: You're never calling mCursor.moveToNext(), nor are you looping through, so your code should only return 1 value if anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List<String> reTurn() throws SQLException 
{
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT EmailNO FROM  Details_Customer ", null);

    int index = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COLUMN_EMAIL);
    while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        emails.add(mCursor.getString(index)); 
        //password = mCursor.getString(11);
    }
    return emails;
}
```

**Added from comment**

From this:

```
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ dbUser.reTurned});
```

I guess that your are trying to put the array of email addresses into an Intent called `email`.  Here is a better approach:

```
public String[] reTurn() throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT EmailNO FROM  Details_Customer ", null);
    String[] emails = new String[mCursor.getCount()];

    int i = 0;
    int index = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COLUMN_EMAIL);
    while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        emails[i++] = mCursor.getString(index); 
        //password = mCursor.getString(11);
    }

    return emails;
}
```

And to put this in an Intent:

```
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, dbUser.reTurned());
```

Lastly, in your new Activity read the email array with:

```
String[] emails = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tanx for the answer but when i'm tying to call it into a activity class it giving me an error... email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ dbUser.reTurned}); in this line RETURNED..I think I need to convert a array to string but I dont know how please help one more time..

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is inside the if statement.

```
emails = mCursor.getString(...);
```

That statement is only being executed once, so you only get one email.

Instead try something like:

```
String[] emails = new String[mCursor.getCount()];
for(int i=0; i<emails.length; i++){
    emails[i] = mCursor.getString(...);
    mCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code as follow to get all mail address :

```
mCursor.moveToFirst();
ArrayList<String> mails = new ArrayList<String>();

if(mCursor.getCount() > 0){ 
    while(!mCursor.isAfterLast()){
         mails.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COLUMN_EMAIL))); 
         mCursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They're all available through the `Cursor` because it's essentially an iterator. See [the Cursor API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html). So  you can pass the cursor as you would an array and iterate over it as needed.

If truly necessary you can copy the results into an array:

```
int n = mCursor.getCount();
String [] emails = new String[n];
int emailColIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COLUMN_EMAIL);
mCursor.moveToFirst();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    emails[i] = mCursor.getString(emailColIndex);
    mCursor.moveToNext();
}
// A good place to close the cursor.
```